# How do I add / remove values to a single cookie with checkboxes in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**EDIT:** I have done more work myself on this solution using JSON and instead of editing the question here I decided to re-write it and make it more clear here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866952/add-remove-values-from-json-string-and-save-to-a-cookie

I have a project that needs to set a cookie with different values which are `classes`from an `input` checkbox.

I have a half working **DEMO HERE** http://jsfiddle.net/chFCx/7/

What I want to do

1. I can only use 1 cookie `filteredName` as I need to read from it on page load - See point 4.
2. When I uncheck a checkbox I want the class name of the input field to added to the cookie (I do this in demo, but I can only hold one value at a time)
3. When I check the checkbox I want the class name of that input field to now be removed from the cookie.
4. When I refresh the page I want the checkboxes which are in the
   cookie to be unchecked.

I am assuming it needs to be some sort of Json String or array that the cookie holds, that is where I run into a problem and need to ask the pro's on here.

My JS so far is as follows, but better viewing the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chFCx/7/) for more context.

```
// Add or Remove Cookie On Change Function
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
    var cookieValue = $.cookie("filteredName"); // for display purposes only
    var checkedClass = $(this).attr('class');

    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        // if checkbox is checked remove checkedClass from cookie
        $('input[type=text].cookieValue').val(cookieValue);  // for display purposes only

    } else {
        // if checkbox is un-checked add checkedClass to cookie
        $.cookie('filteredName', checkedClass, { path: '/' });
        $('input[type=text].cookieValue').val(cookieValue);  // for display purposes only
    }
});
$('input[type=text].cookieValue').val(cookieValue);
// On Page load set checkboxes with class names in cookie to hide checkbox

// Read Cookie
// For each class name in Cookie .prop('checked' true);
```

**EDIT:** I have done more work myself on this solution using JSON and instead of editing the question here I decided to re-write it and make it more clear here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866952/add-remove-values-from-json-string-and-save-to-a-cookie

Comment: Is there any reason you can't have multiple cookied values keyed off the checked classes, or have I missed something?

Comment: @BrMcMullin, well the thing is that the class I am reading into each of the cookies is different for each user in my project and I have no idea of knowing what. So if I was to save each cookie individually with the name as `checkedClass` then I don't know the name of cookies to read/check for when I enter page again. Does that make sense?